# React Redux is not unpacking action types when using bindActionCreators

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

We have an application that is being gradually migrated to new technologies/approaches, like redux-toolkit, typescript and react hooks, however we sometimes have to add functions to unconverted code, but use it into already typescript components for example. One thing that we keep and are waiting for migration is class based components, specially the ones that connect to our redux store.

I have several problems with this approach, but all point to the same epicenter, that is typing the result of bindActionCreators. For example, consider the following `mapDispatchToProps`:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: AppDispatch) {
    return {
        actions: {
            account: bindActionCreators(AccountActions, dispatch)
        }
    };
}
```

If I have a class component, that connects to the store using that function, the following code:

```
class ProfileDetails extends Component<ProfileDetailsProps, ProfileDetailsState> {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.actions.account.getAccount(this.props.userId).then(() => {...});
    }
}
```

Will not be accepted by typescript because it won't unpack the redux action and will not recognize the `.then` on the call (forget the promise structure, I use `async/await` but I thought this serves as better explanation). And this is an approach without redux-toolkit, as on those actions, it is the `.unwrap` function that is said to be nonexistent. The culprit is the function type, that is as follow (notice the unpacked dispatch on the declaration):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gvj5t.png)

The hack I found to work was to unwrap the functions myself, with the following approach:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: AppDispatch) {
    return {
        actions: {
            account: {
                getAccount: (args) => dispatch(AccountActions.getAccount(args))
            }
        }
    };
}
```

I already tried forcing the return type of the `mapDispatchToProps` but always failed to be accepted by the typescript compiler. Already tried to fine tune the generics types of the `bindActionCreators` to no result. I know I may be missing some detailed type for strict the result, but I can not find what to do, documentation and examples I find online are always with hooks and the little I could find, it didn't work on this issue. I also followed the guides on https://github.com/piotrwitek/react-redux-typescript-guide.